# Getting value 0 or 1 from count() of XSL nodesets

Tags: xslt

I have a bunch of nodesets where I want to return "1" instead of "true" when there are more than one hit on count($mynodeset)
Is there more compact/smarter way to to do this in XSLT 1.1?

```
    <xsl:variable name="x5" select="count($mynodeset) != 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="z5">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="x5 = 'true'">1</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: The next time you need it: It's `<xsl:when test="x5 = true()">` or even `<xsl:when test="x5">`, but `<xsl:when test="x5 = 'true'">` should be avoided. Not everything that evaluates to `true` is converted to the string `'true'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the function [`number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-number), which converts a boolean value to 1 or 0.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use the `number` function?

```
<xsl:variable name="x5" select="number(count($mynodeset) != 0)"/>
```

I don't really know XSLT, but this seems quite simple according to:

[XPath `number` function definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-number) (XPath functions are used by [XSLT 1.1 expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#dt-expression))

Comment: Your reference is to XPath 1.0. I'm not sure how XSLT 1.1 enters into the picture, but just in case - don't use it, it's an unfinished and dead standard.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, but XPath is specifically used to define XSLT 1.1 expressions. For this and other reasons, "dead" is a bit strong.